# Building simple Firefox is endless?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, firefox, compilation

I'm trying to build Firefox for the first time, i followed this guides to do so:

[Windows build prerequisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites)
[Simple Firefox build](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Simple_Firefox_build#Get_the_source)

I've installed Visual Studio Professional 2013, Mozilla Build, i've downloaded the source code and the problem is the same:
when i execute the command:

```
    ./mach build
```

it's start building but at this point it does nothing more:

```
 $ ./mach build
 0:09.20 c:\mozilla-build\mozmake\mozmake.EXE -f client.mk -s
 0:42.66 Adding client.mk options from :
 0:42.66     MOZ_OBJDIR=c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32
 0:42.66     OBJDIR=c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32
 0:58.81 cd c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-i686-pc-mingw32
 0:59.09 c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/configure
 1:08.11 loading cache ./config.cache
 1:20.12 checking host system type... i686-pc-mingw32
 1:24.76 checking target system type... i686-pc-mingw32
 1:29.19 checking build system type... i686-pc-mingw32
 1:29.43 checking for mawk... no
 1:29.48 checking for gawk... gawk
 1:30.41 checking for python2.7... /c/mozilla-build/python/python2.7
 1:31.65 Creating Python environment
 1:34.76 checking Python environment is Mozilla virtualenv... yes
 1:35.15 checking for perl5... no
 1:35.37 checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
 1:36.64 checking for gcc... cl
```

I've read that the compile time may take several hours but i've waited 3,5 hours and nothing happened! Could someone help me also simply posting a better guide?

Comment: Check `config.log` in build directory for possible reason

Comment: it doesn't exist maybe because the building process is neither ended, nor crashed, i've just close the prompt after 3,5 hours of nothing!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved! The problem was Visual Studio Professional (uncompatible), it's recommended to use Visual Studio Community Edition 2013! In that way i've solved the problem and now everything works well!!!